# same function but different parameter passing to function

Tags: c, polymorphism, function-pointers

```
struct student {

    char            *s_name;

    struct student_id   s_id;

    /** Number of references to this student. */
    unsigned int         s_ref;

    /** Transcript (singly-linked list, NULL terminator). */
    struct transcript_entry *s_transcript;

    /** Whether or not this student has completed his/her program. */
    student_complete     s_complete;
};

struct student* student_grad_create(const char *name, size_t namelen,
    struct student_id, int phd);

struct student* student_undergrad_create(const char *name, size_t namelen,
    struct student_id);
```

There are three kinds of student, **master student and phd student and undergrad student**.I need to implement a function that called:

```
int student_add_entry(struct student *, struct transcript_entry *);
```

I dont know how I can determine the student type?

should I do the following?

```
int student_add_entry(struct student *undergrad_create, struct transcript_entry *){}
int student_add_entry(struct student *grad_create, struct transcript_entry *){}
```

thanks.

Comment: That's a very funny idea... What would you achieve with that?

Comment: You sure you want `C`? Anyway, how about an `enum` that indicates the student type?

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: Can't you determine this within `student_add_entry()`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth there is no overloading in that function, both are the same with different parameter names.

Comment: "*I dont know how I can determine the student type.*" how would you do this in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `student_type` field to the struct

```
struct student {
    char                    *s_name;
    struct student_id        s_id;
    /** Number of references to this student. */
    unsigned int             s_ref;
    /** Transcript (singly-linked list, NULL terminator). */
    struct transcript_entry *s_transcript;
    /** Whether or not this student has completed his/her program. */
    student_complete         s_complete;
    enum student_type        s_type;
};
```

and you would have an `enum` like

```
enum student_type
{
    UndergraduateStudent,
    MasterStudent,
    PHDStudent
};
```

when creating an instance of `struct student` you would set the `s_type` field, and then use `s_type` everywhere else to determine the type of student.

I would also write a generic function to create an instance of `struct student` passign to it all possible parameters, and if you want for convinience you could also create a function for each specific type, where you might pass default parameters to the generic function.

Comment: Thanks iharob. I added the enum student_type to the struct student. I am just starting learning C. I am working on some problems about the student registration system.

Comment: I have some other questions below, could you please help me have a look?

Comment: @Peter You can't post a question as an answer to another post, you have to post a new question. Please delete the answer and post it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on some student registration system problem.
1. there are three different kinds of student types
2. the undergrad student pass the exam with 50, and master and phd pass with 65
3. Undergraduates must complete 40 courses, MEng students 5 and PhD students 2.

These are the three functionalities I need to implement.
'
Below it is the struct for the transcript_entry:

```
struct transcript_entry {
    enum faculty         te_faculty;
    unsigned int         te_number;
    unsigned int         te_grade;
    /** Number of references to this entry. */
    unsigned int         te_ref;
    /** Next entry in the singly-linked list (or NULL terminator). */
    struct transcript_entry *te_next;
};
```

I implement the following functions:

```
struct transcript_entry* transcript_entry(enum faculty faculty, unsigned int course_number, unsigned int grade){
    struct transcript_entry *trans_entry;
    trans_entry = malloc(sizeof(struct transcript_entry));
    trans_entry->te_faculty = faculty;
    trans_entry->te_number = course_number;
    trans_entry->te_grade = grade;
    trans_entry->te_ref = 1;
    trans_entry->te_next = NULL;
    return trans_entry;
}

/** Deallocate a @ref transcript_entry. */
void    transcript_entry_free(struct transcript_entry *trans_entry){
    free(trans_entry);
}

/** Increment a @ref transcript_entry's refcount. */
void    tehold(struct transcript_entry *trans_entry){
    trans_entry-> te_ref++;
}
```

I looked some tutorials about the reference counting. I dont know my code is make sense or not. So is that mean increment the reference counting ++, or decrement by te_ref--;